# XML and AMPscript -- how do I "BuildRowSetFromString" using data from my API post?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, email, ampscript, xml

I'm trying to build a confirmation email whereupon we create a rowset from a string within the API post.  We currently do this without issue when evaluating data from a Data Extension, but I can't connect the dots when we move this over to an API post.

Current State:

```
%%[
    SET @itempartnumber = LookUp("Data_Extension","Product IDs","EmailAddress",EmailAddr)
    SET @productRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@itempartnumber,"|")
]%%
```

I want to still use BuildRowSetFromString, and the attribute in the XML is , so how do I make the declaration to build that row set from the attribute?

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should add - the current XML post will contain the following:

<Name>itempartnumber</Name>
                    <Value>22031744-1|20511743-1|22196610-1|</Value>

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to build a rowset from the XML and iterate through the nodes.  Looks like one of the node values will contain the pipe-delimited string.  Once you get to that particular value, then you can use the [BuildRowSetFromString()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromString) function.

The function returns a rowset, so it's accessible using the [rowcount()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#RowCount), [row()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#Row), and [field()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/#Field) functions.  You can iterate through the results with a [for loop](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/).

There's a simple example:

```
%%[

Var @i, @testString, @row, @name, @value
Set @testString = BuildRowsetFromString("22031744-1|20511743-1|22196610-1|","|")

for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@testString) do
    Set @row = Row(@testString, @i)
    Set @value = Field(@row,1)
    outputLine(concat("<br>@i: ",@i, " @value: ", @value))
next @i

]%%
```

**Update:** 
Here's an example with the XML payload.  I added a `<part>` node in your XML so I could reference it in the `BuildRowSetFromXML()` function.  There may be a simpler way to reference it.  The `replace()` function was only for displaying the output, nothing else.

```
%%[

Var @i, @testXML, @row, @name, @value

/* if value is coming from API call, use the following */ 
set @testXML = AttributeValue("XML") 

/* set this value for testing purposes */
set @testXML = "<parts><Name>itempartnumber</Name><Value>22031744-1|20511743-1|22196610-1|</Value></parts>" 


set @names = BuildRowsetFromXML(@testXML,"/parts/Name",1)
set @values = BuildRowsetFromXML(@testXML,"parts/Value",1)

for @j = 1 to rowcount(@values) do

  set @row = row(@values,@j)
  set @value = replace(replace(Field(@row, 2),">","&gt;"),"<","&lt;")
  outputLine(concat("<br>@j: ",@j, " @value: ", @value))
  Set @parts = BuildRowsetFromString(@value,"|")

  for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@parts) do
      Set @row = Row(@parts, @i)
      Set @value = Field(@row,1)
      outputLine(concat("<br>@i: ",@i, " @value: ", @value))
  next @i

next @j

]%%
```

**Output:**

```
@j: 1 @value: 22031744-1|20511743-1|22196610-1| 
@i: 1 @value: 22031744-1 
@i: 2 @value: 20511743-1 
@i: 3 @value: 22196610-1 
@i: 4 @value:
```

Comment: Thanks Adam!  I understand what you're trying to do, but what I'm missing is how we populate the @teststring with values from the API post, and not hard-coded like you have it now.                  

Here's what I'm thinking:                   

SET "at sign"productNumberRows = BuildRowsetFromString(AttributeValue(itempartnumber),"|")
                               
Am I on the right track?

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Comment: Sorry for the additional questions, but I still don't get it... in the code you have above you reference the actual data from the XML where you SET the variable "TestXML" with data -- how can I accomplish this when the XML will be different for every email?

Comment: `@names` and `@values` are returning arrays based on the XPATH referenced in the function.  As long as the node names stay the same, the data can vary.

Comment: I apologize, as I'm a neophyte on this stuff... in your example, the API and the AMPscript seem to be one in the same.  I'm trying to store a template in ET and trigger the email with the XML.  

If I have a Data Extension, then I use a LookUp funtion -- and the email works fine.  When I trigger via the XML, I'm not sure how my stored template can reference the XML, and in the example you have SET the XML right in the AMPscript

Comment: I added additional example to my answer. You'll need to pass an attribute named `XML` in your triggered API call and reference it using the `AttributeValue()` function in your email.   The `XML` attribute will contain any XML you need to pass.

Comment: Adam, I greatly appreciate your willingness to help me!!  It's truly amazing.  My current XML posts the data like this:

 <Attributes>           <Name>orderstatus</Name>
                    <Value>received</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>orderdate</Name>
                    <Value>2015-06-30 11:10:36.956</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>billmerchant</Name>
                    <Value>moneris</Value>
                </Attributes>

Do I need to restructure this altogether?

Comment: If that's the case, then you can just reference the attributes like this: `AttributeValue("orderstatus")` or `AttributeValue("orderdate")`

Comment: Here's a sample SOAP envelope that has your attributes and an XML payload:  http://pastebin.com/6WXffQW7