# Kind of Lost --> How Do I reference the XML in my Email Template when Triggering an Email via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript, xml

I'm lost, and need some guidance.  I've built a Purchase Confirmation email and when testing I reference a Data Extension and everything works fine.  However, when I want to move the data reference to the information contained in the API post, I'm not sure how I reference that in the HTML.

I've created the Triggered Send Data Extension... but I'm stuck.

Please help!

Comment: I found this tidbit in the documentation:

set @xml = confirmation_xml

how do I reference the XML when I begin building rowsetfromstring and such?

Comment: Please post the XML payload you're wanting to process in your email.

Comment: partial code:  


%%[

SET "at symbol"itempartnumber =  itempartnumber

SET "at symbol"billfirstname = billfirstname

SET "at symbol"billlastname = billlastname

SET "at symbol"ordershippingcharge = ordershippingcharge

and I'm trying to figure out --> how do I reference that "itempartnumber" comes from the XML post that contains the personalization data?

from what I'm seeing here and in the documentation, it appears that I need to put in something like SET "at symbol"itempartnumber = (XML//itempartnumber) 

or something like that... but, this is where I can't connect the dots.

Comment: Please refer to the second example I provided on:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82456/xml-and-ampscript-how-do-i-buildrowsetfromstring-using-data-from-my-api-pos